# Why assigning a function as variable is faster in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

Today I observed an interesting behavior using Python.

```
def f():
    ls1 = []
    for x in range(1000000):
        ls1.append(x)
%timeit f()
77.2 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And tested a second function.

```
def f2():
    ls1 = []
    lsa = ls1.append
    for x in range(1000000):
        lsa(x)        
%timeit f2()
56 ms ± 566 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Assigning append to a variable was faster than using append inside the loop.

Why the second function is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a dynamic language. Attribute lookup is comparable to a dict lookup, so in the first scenario, you first lookup `ls1` in the local scope and then lookup `append` on the `ls1`-object each of 1000000 iterations. In the second scenario you lookup the `append` on `ls1` only once, and then 1 million iterations where you lookup `lsa` in the local scope

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second function, you have the reference to the method already and can call it directly in every iteration, whereas in the first function, it has to first find the `append` method of the `ls1` object first in every iteration before making the call.